# What do we call different full row rank matrices with the same inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, terminology, pseudoinverse, generalized-inverse

Consider matrices $A_1, A_2,..., A_n$ such that they have generalized inverses $B_1, B_2,..., B_n$. (Matrices don't have to be square.)

If $~ \forall i \neq j: {1<i,j<n}, A_i \neq A_j , B_i=B_j$, then in mathematical terminology, what do we call the $A_i$ matrices?